# Is there any way to find only visible elements on python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm scrapping comments of a article list, and I have to make a clean screenshot of it.
So I have tried below a routine.

1. scrapping & taking a scr shot
2. click load_more btn
3. hide taked comments element
4. scrapping & taking a new scr shot
   ~ repeating ...

But as N (the number of comments) gets bigger, it takes geometric times t^N to review it since selenium have to cover all preceded comments which are already taken.

So I'm just wonder is there any way to improve it like

1. Any way to get only visible contents on selenium
2. or .. any setting on elements to make it not detectable by selenium.

(I cannot use deleting elements becaused load more button's js does not work after delete any parts of comments.)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, ""))) You can look into webdriver wait and visibility_of_all_elements to grab a group of x items.

Comment: why do you hide the previous comments instead of scrolling to new ones? moreover, you should provide your full code so that we can help